# Unable to reach callback URL

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've been using the Instagram RealTime API for some time now without problems. However, I switched hosting server for my website a couple of days ago, and since then I've been having problems registering subscriptions.

To debug the problem I've been using powershell to invoke the POST command to add new subscriptions like this:

```
$postParams = @{callback_url='http://example.com/callback';object='tag';aspect='media';object_id='sometag';client_id='CLIENT_ID';client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET'}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/ -Method POST -Body $postParams
```

If I invoke that on my developer machine, I get a 200 in response and I see that the subscription is listed if I call:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&client_id=CLIENT_ID

However, If I invoke that exact command in powershell on my webserver where my site is hosted I get a 400 with error message 'Unable to reach callback URL "http://example.com/callback"'

What could be the source of this problem? I've tried to register a new application, but I got the same error there. At first I thought it had something to do with DNS issues, but since Instagram are able to reach http://example.com/callback when I issue the command from my developer machine, shouldn't they be able to reach that same URL even if my request comes from another server?

Comment: You might be interested in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32479100/5130253

Comment: @sofia Will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

The error `Unable to reach callback URL` might be misleading. I had the same issue, same command, different IP and in one case it works, in the other it does not. I suspect it is an Instagram issue rejecting subscriptions from some IPs while others not.

Comment: did you ever figure out the reason behind the different IPs working & not working?

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using a redirection from a host to my local servlet and for some reason the callback URL was not acceptable. I fixed this and then used the API console as well as a [java library](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram) to try to make subscriptions. In both cases the subscription was successful about 1 out of 4 times and the rest failed with `Unable to reach callback URL` error. The reason might be (I can only suspect) Instagram's policy `..you should acknowledge the POST within a 2 second timeout..` and maybe my servlet is too slow (?)